# Visual Studio created app.config files on DLL projects. Does it actually make any use of them?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, app-config

Recently on a NuGet package update, Visual Studio created app.config files on DLL projects, containing dependencies. Does it actually make any use of them? Like, I know `System.Configuration` only loads the .config file of the entry executable.

Should I simply delete them, or are they used by Visual Studio in any way, shape or form? (like, merging their contents with the ones in the projects that depend on them)